# Get text of table data even if child exists - LXML

Tags: python, html, lxml

Trying to pull text from the row in a table within HTML where each table data tag may or may not have a nested tag.  Been playing with lxml library in python to achieve the data extraction but I can't quite figure out how to best handle this issue:

```
from lxml import etree, html


s = """<table>
  <tr><th>Event</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td><code>d</code></td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
  <tr><td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td></tr>
</table>
"""

table = etree.HTML(s).findall("body/table/tr/td")

rows = iter(table)
headers = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row 3']
for row in rows:
    values = [col.text for col in row]
    print dict(zip(headers, values))
```

That's the code I have so far, lifted from another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following, using the `lxml` parser from within the BeautifulSoup library:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

s = """<table>
  <tr><th>Event</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td><code>d</code></td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
  <tr><td>g</td><td>h</td><td>i</td></tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

headers = [h.text for h in soup.find_all('th')]
rows = soup.find_all('tr')[1:]

dic_list = []
for row in rows:
    data = [i.text for i in row]
    dic = {k:v for k,v in zip(headers, data)}
    dic_list.append(dic)

df = pd.DataFrame(dic_list)
print(df)
```

This results in:

```
  End Date Event Start Date
0        c     a          b
1        f     d          e
2        i     g          h
```

Comment: Hmm, forgot about BS.  Use of pandas is overkill but looks nice.  Will try it now.

Comment: @MarkII yes there are certainly more simple ways to approach this, but these two libraries are very well suited for this type of task